# PHP - How many times the page has been viewed

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, include

I want PHP to be able to echo the amount of times the page has been viewed. Being a server side scripting language I'm fairly confident there's a way.

This is what I'm thinking...

main.php

```
<body>
<?php
include("views.php");
$views = $views + 1;
echo $views;
?>
</body>
```

views.php

```
<?php $views = 0; ?>
```

This works, but does not update. (It will display 1, but will not keep counting upon refresh.)

Comment: If you want the $views to update, don't write, `<?php $views = 0; ?>` Are you using a database?

Comment: `file_put_contents('count.txt', ((int) file_get_contents('count.txt')) + 1);`

Comment: or a google analytics account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the variable `$views` does not persist from view to view. In fact, the next time someone comes back to your website `$views` would have been reset to 0. You'll need to take a look at some form of persistence to store the total number of views.

One way that you can accomplish this is to use a database or via a file. If you are using files, you can do the following inside of your views.php file.

**views.php**

```
$views = 0;
$visitors_file = "visitors.txt";

// Load up the persisted value from the file and update $views
if (file_exists($visitors_file))
{
    $views = (int)file_get_contents($visitors_file) 
}

// Increment the views counter since a new visitor has loaded the page
$views++;

// Save the contents of this variable back into the file for next time
file_put_contents($visitors_file, $views);
```

**main.php**

```
include("views.php");
echo $views;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to *store* the data somewhere. Variables do not keep their state between requests. `$views = 0` always means `$views = 0`, regardless of whether that variable is being `included` or not.

Write the number of views to a file (`file_put_contents`, `file_get_contents`) or to a database to store them permanently.

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh the page, the state is not saved. This `$views` is set to 0 everytime you begin, and gets incremented by 1.

To increment the count and save the value, you will need to persist the number by either using a database or a file.

Answer (score 0):

Great idea will be to use a database like MySQL. There are a lot of articles over the Internet how to set it up and use with PHP.

What you would probably want to do - update a page row in 'views' every time page is accessed. Simplest way is something like this:

```
<?php
/* don't forget to connect and select a database first */
$page = 'Home Page'; // Unique for every page
mysql_query("UPDATE views SET num = num + 1 WHERE page = '$page'");
```